# TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable, while doing element.screenshot_as_png

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, typeerror

AIM: Save a screenshot of a specific element in selenium [Python3]

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pyautogui as pog
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

print("Hello There!")
url = "https://uk.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/products/trunk-wallet-nvprod2530051v"
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
AAC = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/ul/li[3]/button")
AAC.screenshot_as_png('elemenent.png')
```

ERROR:

```
    AAC.screenshot_as_png('elemenent.png')
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this? <3 in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Instead of**

```
AAC.screenshot_as_png('elemenent.png')
```

**Try This:**

```
screenshot_as_bytes = AAC.screenshot_as_png
with open('elemenent.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(screenshot_as_bytes)
```

**Check below my Explanation:**

`AAC.screenshot_as_png` is already the screenshot in bytes, all you have to do is to save it. If try to call it like `AAC.screenshot_as_png()` then the execution will be attempted on the bytes, hence the error: `TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

This method for taking a screenshot worked for me:

```js
browser.save_screenshot("d:/Images/1.png")
```